# WP - нет доступа к страницам сайта

Tags: wordpress, apache2, raspberry-pi, site, raspbian

Делаю сайт на WP. Хостинг на Raspberry Pi, Apache2.

Пытался получить доступ к странице из меню на сайте - ничего не вышло и он выдал такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная страница существует:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу получить доступ к ней только с главной страницы сайта(у меня на главной расположены все страницы - тема TwentySeventeen)

Как мне исправить это?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

В сайтах на вордпрессе ссылки на всё и вся хранятся в базе данных и хранятся там как абсолютные пути, то есть путь включает в себя протокол, домен и собственно адрес страницы. Зачем так делается и почему так лучше и надёжнее с точки зрения вордпресса - отдельный вопрос, погуглите.

У вас в адресе к странице (постоянная ссылка) имеет место быть фэйковый ip-адрес: 192.168.1.8. Подобные адреса используются в локальных сетях и на локальных веб-серверах. На хостинге этот адрес должно заменять на реальное имя домена сайта.

Делать это лучше всего не вручную, путём замены всех вхождений адреса в базе данных на домен, а при помощи специальных плагинов. Лично я использую плагин [Duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

Comment: а где нужная функция в нём?

Comment: нашёл только про бекап и востановление из него

Comment: На локальном веб-сервере установите плагин, например Duplicator, как я написал выше. Затем создайте с его помощью резервную копию сайта. На хостинге в папку с сайтом загрузите только её (файл с архивом сайта и installer.php). Всё, что вы загрузили в эту папку ранее - сотрите. Перейдите по адресу http://ваш_домен/installer.php и следуя инструкции распакуйте сайт на хостинге. Остальное плагин сделает за вас.

Comment: я перенёс сайт с локального компа на свой сервер(он тоже в локалке находится и 192.168.1.8 - его ip)

Comment: функция миграции - только на Pro версии

Comment: Вам не нужна про версия и функция миграции. Посмотрите [любую инструкцию](https://youtu.be/ua4NZbt7mvs) по работе с плагином. Плагин справится сам. Но у вас, похоже что-то другое. Как выглядит ваше меню в вордпрессе? Как в нём прописана ссылка на страницу?

Comment: уже запустилось

Comment: пишет `Installing database`

Comment: сайт переутстановил, но всё равно та же ошибка

Comment: можно вас в скайп для помощи?

Comment: В рабочее время совсем никак, но на SO есть чат, мы можем продолжить обсуждение в [нём](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115604/discussion-between-kvaksman-play-and-quazimorda).